# Where did this JFrame object get its height and width from?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to find out where my `JFrame` object got its height and width from in the `setMinimumSize()` method, because the program creates a frame and it works although I didn't declare the height and width of my frame.

The code:

```
public MapEditor() throws FileNotFoundException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Aliengame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension((int) (frame.getWidth() * 1.2), (int) (frame.getHeight() * 1.2)));
    System.out.println(frame.getHeight());
```

Comment: The height information is a combination of things. Based on your example, I suspect that the frame's height is coming from the frame's borders, as no other content all probably make the frame appear as nothing but the title bar (and surrounding border if the OS supplies one)

Comment: Oh, and `pack` is when the frame is actually been sized

Comment: `frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension((int) (frame.getWidth() * 1.2), (int) (frame.getHeight() * 1.2)));` What on Earth is the thinking with this line of code?!? As mentioned by @MadProgrammer, the frame will be sized appropriate to the content on the call to `pack()`.